# Cardinality of vertex Cover and matching (König's Theorem)

Tags: graph-theory

- Let G be a graph with $G=(V,E)$.
- We define $f(G)$ as the cardinality of the minimum vertex cover in $G$ and $h(G)$ as the cardinality of the largest matching in G.
- We can assume, for every graph G, that $\;f(G) \geq h(G) $

**To be proven**

> For each $\epsilon>0$ there is a graph with $\;f(G)\geq(2-\epsilon)\cdot h(G)$

**Question:** How can I proof this for every $\epsilon>0$?

I don't have any idea how to proceed. Induction won't also work because we are not in set of natural numbers

Thanks for any suggestion or hint to help me to proceed to completing a proof of the proposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a graph with vertices $\{v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_{3n-1}, v_{3n}\}$ such that $\{v_{3i+1}, v_{3i+2}, v_{3i + 3}\}$ consititute a triangle for $\forall 0 \leq i < n$ and there is no other edges. In other words, the graph consists of $n$ isolated triangles. In this graph, $f(G)= 2n$ and $h(G) = n$. Therefore, $f(G) \geq 2h(G)$.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not valid for each $\epsilon$ I think?

Comment: @user1299292 Note that $\epsilon > 0$. Thus $f(G) \geq 2h(G) > (2-\epsilon)h(G)$.

Comment: Okay, could you explain why exactly $f(G)=2n$ and $h(G)=n$? And for example when I have $n=2$ the vertices are $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5,v_6\}$, is the Graph G then given by $G=\{\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5,v_6\},\{(v_1,v_2),(v_2,v_3),(v_3,v_1), (v_4,v_5),(v_5,v_6),(v_6,v_4)\}$? Didn't understand this so far :(

Comment: @user1299292 In this graph with $n = 2$, to cover all edges, there must be  $4$ vertices (exactly two from each triangle) in a minimum vertex cover, thus $f(G) = 4 = 2 \cdot 2$ and a maximum matching must consist of exactly one edge from each triangle, thus $h(G) = 2$.